# What does it mean "unable to get source run" while connecting to Wercker api?

Tags: api, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, wercker

While trying to trigger a Wercker CI/CD pipeline via API, I got the following error:

```
{
  "error": "unable to get source run",
  "message": "unable to get source run",
  "code": 13
}
```

My command is:

```
POST https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/runs
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I was pointing to a pipeline not connected with the versioning system, one step further down the workflow.
Wercker API only allows you to execute "root" pipeline.